# jQuery selector performance: $('#a p') versus $('p', $context) versus $context.find('p')

Tags: jquery, performance

If I have already got, in my variable `$a_div`, a jQuery object for the DIV in the following markup and I want to find the Ps

```
<div id="a">
    ...
    <p>...</p>
    ...
</div>
```

Is there a significant performance difference between these ways to select the P elements in the DIV?

```
$('#a p')
$('p', $a_div)
$a_div.find('p')
```

And if so, do you know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of thing is usually browser dependent, but I'd use the 3rd one.

First one, browsers with `querySelectorAll` will make use of it, so performance should be good.

In browsers that don't support `qsa`, I think Sizzle finds *all* `p` elements on the page, and traverses their ancestors to see if there's a `#a` element.

```
$('#a p')
```

---

I wouldn't use the second one at all, because it gets changed to the third one in the background.

```
$('p', $a_div)   // becomes $a_div.find('p')
```

---

Whether via `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByTagName`, you're starting from a known point in the DOM, and only searching within it, so I'd bet that this will generally be fastest.

```
$a_div.find('p')
```

Comment: Very useful background information—thanks, Patrick. I am shocked at $('#a p'). I had been preferring it because I read, some time ago, that it is nice and fast. I should remember a couple of old maxims: 1) Don’t believe everything you read on the Internet. 2) Doveryai, no proverya.

Comment: @fsb: You're welcome. I must say that after running your revision to the jsPerf, I'm pretty surprised at the performance of the full selector as well. Goes to show that performance testing  is a good idea. Overall, my policy is to always try to avoid re-selecting DOM elements that I've already selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can always test it out - http://jsperf.com/some-jquery-selectors-performance-tests

Second one seems to be about thrice as fast as the first one, and third one slightly more. This would definitely differ depending on the rest of your HTML structure, but I'm pretty sure the first one will always remain the slowest.

Comment: That's a wonderful test tool. Thanks for referring me to it. I modified the markup to put the #a DIV in a page with lots of other DOM nodes and `$('#a p')` got a lot slower.